Obtener Video en vivo de una camara v380 con python
Tengo una cámara de seguridad v380, quiero con Python y cv2 capturar el video en vivo de esa cámara, no conozco sus protocolos ni nada sobre la cámara.
La cámara tiene un QR y este es su contenido "V380^77154481^AWT3610E^3^2^1909170002^20231108114801"
La cámara está en la LAN con la IP "192.168.0.101" y tiene dos puertos abiertos
8800 Sun Web Server Admin Service
9800 WebDav Source Port
Esa es la única información que tengo sobre la cámara.
¡Por favor, ayúdenme, gracias!
ya intente esto https://gist.github.com/SolveSoul/9be5d9599c8b4b59f7cfa4cd0ce79c9c#file-ceshi-ini  varias veces, pero no funciono.

Por favor comparte el código con lo que hayas intentado y los errores que te estés encontrando. Tal y como está la pregunta ahora, necesita detalles para aclarar el problema, o puede acabar cerrada al no ajustarse bien al formato del sitio. Lee [ask] para más información.

Esta pregunta es similar a: Obtener Video Stream de una camara v380 con python. Si crees que es diferente, por favor edita tu pregunta aclarando por qué es diferente y/o por qué las respuestas a esa pregunta no ayudan a resolver tu problema.
